# Codeigniter form validation set_checkbox() not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Set_checkbox() is not working although all is set?
I do non compulsory post validation and only trim it to get the value pushed for call_back... When I post the form and other validations are not met, it should go back to the form. When it does, is the checkbox not selected after post even if was checked before submit.
What am I missing?

Form / View:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hsnb" value="25.00"  name="u" onclick="Calculate()" <?=set_checkbox('u', '25')?>>
```

The controller:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

if($this->input->post('submit2')) {
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('u', 'u', 'trim');
if ($this->form_validation->run() === false)
{
$this->load->view('form', $data);
}
else
{
$this->load->view('form', $data);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically the value you submitted is returned back to the form you submitted. using the `set_checkbox()` function, you will check if the submitted value matches the checkbox element's value in which this function is resided.

Why don't you try:

```
<?=set_checkbox('u', '25.00')?>
```

the exact value you set for the box!

[Codeigniter Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_checkbox)

Comment: Lol! Thanks @Afghan Amazing how once can miss such a small thingy!